# Moran's test using the residuals of logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, autocorrelation, spatial

I have fitted a **logistic regression** and I would like to check for spatial autocorrelation in the residuals of the model. Is it statistically correct to implement the Moran's test using the residuals of that model?
Here is an example (in R) to illustrate my question.

```
# Load packages
library(sp)
library(spdep)

# Get spatial data 
data(meuse)
spdat <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(meuse$x, meuse$y), meuse)
plot(spdat)

# Weights matrix with the 10 nearest neighbors, in weights list form 
lstw  <- nb2listw(knn2nb(knearneigh(spdat, k = 10)))

# Model (logistic regression)
model <- glm(lime ~ cadmium + copper + lead + zinc,
         data = spdat, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(model)

# Moran's test using the residuals of the model
moran.test(residuals.glm(model), lstw)
```