# Moran's test using residuals of linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, autocorrelation, spatial

A follow up question to [Moran's test using the residuals of logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305199/morans-test-using-the-residuals-of-logistic-regression)

Is this doable on linear mixed effects models (lme)? I want to use Moran's I to determine if accounting for correlation structure removes the spatial autocorrelation of my model residuals.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, I believe that this would work.

I would suggest to check what type of residuals are required by `moran.test`: deviance, response, partial, etc. `glm.summaries` defaults to deviance residuals, so if this is what you want to test, that's fine. But if you want the residuals on the response scale, that is, the observed response (0 or 1) minus the fitted values, then you would need to use `type = "response"`

Note that in the linked question, you use the default deviance residuals.

When extracting residuals from an `lme` object, there are similar options for type: deviance, pearson, working, response, partial